# TableAdapter GetData method fails

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm using a TableAdapter to populate a DataTable.
The TableAdapter has two queries: the default one, and one that joins several tables.
When I use the default one, everything works fine. **But when I use the custom one (named GetDataJoined) it terminates the application (no exception, no warning, nothing)**. I'm running the application in Debug mode.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    Vozila.ID, Vozila.Registracija, Vozila.Vin, Vozila.Opis, 
    Vozaci.ImePrezime, MarkaVozilo.Text, TipVozilo.Opis AS Expr1 
FROM    Vozila 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vozaci ON Vozila.VozacId = Vozaci.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MarkaVozilo ON Vozila.MarkaId = MarkaVozilo.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TipVozilo ON Vozila.TipId = TipVozilo.ID
```

Here is the code where it fails:

```
VozilaDataSet fullView = new VozilaDataSet();
VozilaTableAdapter adapter = new VozilaTableAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table=adapter.GetDataJoined(); //<-- the execution hangs for a while here, and then terminates
grdVozila.DataSource = table;
```

I'm using MS Sql Server Express as RDBMS.

[UPDATE - GetDataJoined() code]

```
public virtual VozilaDataSet.VozilaDataTable GetDataJoined() {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        VozilaDataSet.VozilaDataTable dataTable = new VozilaDataSet.VozilaDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Is the default one returning the same number of columns like the custom one?

Comment: Does this query return anything at all when executed directly on the DB?

Comment: @MIlen No, the two have different number of columns. Is that a problem?

Comment: @st4hoo Yes, I have inserted one row for testing purposes, and the query works fine.

Comment: Could you show `GetDataJoined()` method body?

Comment: Have you tried to surround `adapter.GetDataJoined()` call with try..catch and catch exception?

Comment: @st4hoo Yep... Now it shows. Turns out, some constraints are violated in the db. But, can I turn on these exceptions to break execution automatically?

Comment: yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Comment: Have you tried your query in SQL server?